# Chartjs labels with Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, label

I have a Chart.js with values from a Javascript array which looks exactly like that:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"0":"8.4113","2":"9.5231","3":"9.0655","4":"7.8400"}');
```

And here I give the "obj" array to the chartjs which works fine and fills out the bars:

```
var barChartData = {
        labels : obj1,

        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : obj

            }
        ]

    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    }

    </script>
```

But as you can see there is a second array called "obj1" which stores the names for the labels. This one looks exactly like that:

```
 var obj1 = JSON.parse('{"0":"name1","2":"name2","3":"name3","4":"name4"}');
```

This second array does not fill out the labels like the other array, the labels are still empty. I have no idea why it does not work like the data:"".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```js
function convertToArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return obj[key];
    });
}

var obj = JSON.parse('{"0":"8.4113","2":"9.5231","3":"9.0655","4":"7.8400"}');
var obj1 = JSON.parse('{"0":"name1","2":"name2","3":"name3","4":"name4"}');

obj = convertToArray(obj);
obj1 = convertToArray(obj1);

var barChartData = {
    labels : obj1,
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : obj

        }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
    responsive : true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

`Object.keys(obj)` returns an array of object's properties and then we use the `Array#map()` function to convert these keys to actual values. The `Array#map()` then returns a new array containing just the values.

Comment: I might should say, that the arrays are dynamic so I do not want to add Data manually. Obj and Obj1 are from a Database...

Comment: I think I need to get obj1 without the key just the names in an array like you said: `['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']` but didn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I understand, use the code I added in my answer below to convert your data model to an array.

Comment: I tried that now it displays the chart but every lable is called "NaN" instead of "name1","name2" and so on...

Comment: ok i upated the answer again, the culprit was `parseFloat()` in `convert()` function.

Comment: That worked fine, thank you this function is very useful.